# Stretchy collectionView embedded in a tableviewHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my app, I have a screen like below:

[image]

I want to implement a stretchy header for my tableView which must stretch the imageViews embedded in a `collectionView` which is embedded in the `tableViewHeader`.

I tried to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` in the tableView but it's totally buggy because I should modify the collectionView + cell at the same time:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let scrollY = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if scrollY < 0 {
        var tmpFrame = tableViewHeader.frame
        tmpFrame.origin.y = scrollY
        tmpFrame.size.height = tableViewHeader.frame.height - scrollY
        tableViewHeader.frame = tmpFrame
    }
}
```

Do you know how to implement this feature or have you some hint to help me. Thank you.

Comment: Do you must use collection view ? As far as I can see this looks like uipageview

Comment: hmm that's seems a nice idea. I'll try that ty :)

Comment: @Miknash Thx, using a scrollView instead of the collectionView was the point. Put your comment as an answer if you want me to validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use `UICollectionView`, but you can acomplish this with `UIPageView` or `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIPageViewController` and embed it as subview to 'UITableView', so it will not only be stretchy, but will save its vertical pin gesture along with horizontal on 'UIPageViewController'.

P.S: I've been struggling with the same problem and implemented sample [project](https://github.com/Erumaru/ios-table-view-stretchy-header).